# On tablet orientation change app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, master-detail

Im trying to implement a MasterDetail layout and i get an error when i try to rotate it. any advice?

MainActivity (oncreate)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.detailsConatiner) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.MainContainer, new MoviesFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        } else mTwoPane = false;
    }
}
```

layout/activity_main

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
    android:name="com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.fragment.MoviesFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

layout-sw600dp

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
        android:name="com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.fragment.MoviesFragment"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailsConatiner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MoviesFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setView(mView);

    FetchMoviesTask fetchMoviesTask = new FetchMoviesTask(getActivity(), mView);
    fetchMoviesTask.fetchMovieData(true);
    return mView;
}
```

This is the error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
```

It corresponds to the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Any hint at what im doing wrong?

*edit- FULL LOG CAT

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2, PID: 4382
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2/com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.fragment.MoviesFragment did not create a view.
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2446)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at com.example.strahinja.popularmoviesp2.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you post the full logcat with the exception?

Comment: just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace R.id.MainContainer with R.id.detailsContainer and new MoviesFragment() with new MoviesDetailFragment().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.detailsConatiner) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.detailsConatiner, new MoviesDetailFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    } else mTwoPane = false;
  }
}
```